# Galaxy S won't boot, stuck in recovery mode

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

My galaxy S was working good until about a month ago when it froze and needed to reboot.  Now when it boots, a screen showing a mobile phone and a computer and an exclamation mark in the middle is appearing.  How can I resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your phone is stuck in recovery mode, you can try these steps to force it to boot to Android:

- Remove the battery, wait a couple of minutes, then put the battery back in.
- Turn on phone and see if it still boots into recovery mode.
- If it does still boot into recovery mode, hold down "Volume Up" button and then press the Power button.
- The recovery menu should appear; using the Volume buttons to move the cursor, select "Reboot system" and press the power button to select it.
- If it still boots to Recovery, go into the Recovery menu again and select "Factory Reset/Wipe Data".  Your phone should be reset back to factory defaults and boot properly.

If none of this works, most likely it is a hardware issue and you'll need to get the phone itself looked at by a technician.